# How to read all Linux environment variables into R in a Docker container?

Tags: r, shiny, environment-variables, azure-webapps

I am trying to make an R-Shiny web app secure be getting all of my db credentials out of the code. I am using Azure Webapps for containers and in run time I set environment variables securily via Azure Keyvault.

However, when I use Sys.getenv()

> Sys.getenv("AzureSQL_Prod")

... the specified environment variable does not appear. So the questions is why? And how do I get R to understand that I need to access this environment variable?

Comment: You forgot the `Sys.` above - however meybe just a typo. To get all available variables just use `Sys.getenv()` without an argument - you might want to check if "AzureSQL_Prod" appears in there.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. And thank for the comment :) It does not appear in the variables shown in the console...

Answer (score 0):

R environment variables are generated from the .Renviron file - see this Rstudio link for more details (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf).

When you invoke `Sys.getenv()`, the R process searches for R environment variables - not system environment variables.

One option to get around this is to create a `.Renviron` file - see the link above for details.

An alternative is to retrieve system environment variables explicitly from your R code. My approach is as follows:

```r
system("printenv MY_ENV_VARIABLE", intern = TRUE)
```

This should output the string corresponding to your system variable. The `intern = TRUE` allows you to save the output as a variable in your R environment.